# How could one 'sit on the hearth'?

Tags: prepositions

[From Dickens](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/786/786-h/786-h.htm):

> Dear reader!  It rests with you and me, whether, in our two fields of action, similar things shall be or not.  Let them be!  We shall **sit with lighter bosoms on the hearth**, to see the ashes of our fires turn gray and cold.

But hearths seem not to have places for sitting **on** them, except maybe the narrow shelfs fit for cats and suchlike creatures. I would understand 'sit **by** the hearth' or 'sit **close** to the hearth', but why **on**?

I found some instances of the same use of the *on* preposition at Google Books, like this one:

> I took a couple of snap shots of Judy, who had moved to sit **on** the hearth to get closer to the warm fire.

and

> She set down the bellows and stood, saying, “Please, sit **on** the hearth and dry yourself. And can I get you anything? Hot tea . . . or wine?” Finn sat down **on** the wide stone hearth, and held his hands up to the flames. “No, thank you,” he replied,  ...

Could one sit **on** any hearth or only on a hearth that has a special area extending into the room?

I just can't help recalling [James Winterbottom, Esq.](http://books.google.ru/books?id=f3-O64MBeXsC&lpg=PA83&ots=aBPwI2JE5n&dq=%22sat%20on%20the%20fire%22%20winterbottom&hl=ru&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q=%22sat%20on%20the%20fire%22%20winterbottom&f=false) when I read "please, sit *on* the hearth". (0:

Comment: **[hearth](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hearth)**: "the floor of a fireplace in a house and the area around it". -- It looks like *hearth* includes the area around it. I'm not sure though; I don't have one. :-)

Comment: It is not uncommon for the fireplace to be on a raised platform making tending the fire easier. An added benefit is that this provides a bench to sit on and warm your back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hearth&source=lnms&tbm=isch) for "hearth" you will see that many fireplaces have a raised "bench" of brick or stone about 1ft off the ground, which is perfect for sitting "on."

As a child this was a common setting for taking our family holiday photos. In Dickens' time I imagine it was the warmest, brightest place in the house for the family to gather,  tell/listen to stories, and simply watch the fire. His quote refers to this situation.

As modern homes have made fireplaces more an aesthetic addition than a necessary one, the hearth has probably shrunken a bit to be less for sitting on, and more for staring at.
The "hearth" can refer generally to areas around a fireplace. The "mantle" is a more specific term for the "narrow shelf for cats" above the fireplace.

Answer (score 3):

Ditto @mc01. I'd add that a hearth is typically made of brick or stone, while a floor is normally wood or tile. So if the fireplace has a section of this brick or stone extending several feet out from the chimney et al -- which it often does -- this whole brick section is normally called the "hearth", and someone could well sit on it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One can sit on the right hand side of the hearth. The raised hearth makes it easier to see inside the stove when you reload it.